# What causes the error in Dart Class '_WebSocketImpl' has no instance method 'send'?

Tags: websocket, dart

Okay so I have created a websocket server using the various tutorials such as:

http://japhr.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/dart-client-and-server-websockets.html
http://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch05.html

However when I run the server side code and try sending data to a client it comes up with

`Class '_WebSocketImpl' has no instance method 'send'`

What has the send method been changed to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so the issue here was basically all the tutorials on the web and many Google Talk pages had outdated information. I was told several times by people that its the `send` function and that there is an error somewhere else in my code if its not working.

Its actually a really simple change, `send` has been renamed to `add`.

http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_io/WebSocket.html

Incredibly frustrating if you accidentally miss it whilst reading the documentation.